# Largest value of time for which solution of PDE can be continued to $[0, t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

It's a promblem from Arnold ODE book.

Find the largest value of $t$ for which the solution of the Cauchy problem
$$
u_{t}+u u_{x}=-\sin x,\left.\quad u\right|_{t=0}=0
$$
can be continued to $[0, t)$.

I tried to find characteristics with $$\left.\quad u\right|_{t=0}=0$$But i have a bit of trouble with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you managed to do so far? Do you know the characteristic equations? Have you solved them?

Comment: Characteristic equations:
\begin{array}{l}
\dot{t}=1 \\
\dot{x}=u \\
\dot{u}= - sinx
\end{array}.
I know 1 first integral.